# Plotting data using Basemap Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to plot a two dimensional image(height=3631,width=1311) using basemap with my latitude and longitude grid points also of the same dimension....Following is my code which I am using along with the images of my lat and long grids:

```
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lon1, lat1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
m = Basemap(projection='lcc', resolution='c',
            width=3.2E6, height=4E6, 
            lat_0=21, lon_0=79,)
m.shadedrelief(scale=0.5)
m.pcolormesh(lon, lat, image,
             latlon=True, cmap='Reds')

plt.clim(image.min(), image.max())
m.drawcoastlines(color='black')

plt.title('BAND INFO')
plt.colorbar(label='Scale');
```

[latitude list partial snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGTOX.jpg)
[longitude list partial snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4y46.jpg)

Using the above code I am getting the following output with no image data displayed on the map but colorbar is displaying the correct min. and max. values of the image:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTQuL.jpg)

Can anyone kindly let me know what is the issue since I am not getting any error after running the code....any help will be appreciated....